# how to use "for" loop PHP to make multiple variable in PHP,

Tags: php

i have more then 5 link for image, so i want to make like this,
$p_image1, $p_image2, $p_image3, $p_image4, $p_image5

but i dont understand why my cod is not work...

this is my code for get array data:

```
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($koneksi,$_GET['i']);
    $query = mysqli_query($koneksi,"SELECT * FROM `tb_produk` WHERE `p_id` = '$id'");
$get = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
```

this is my code for loop:

```
if ($j_image > 1) {
   for ($i = 1; $i <= $j_image; $i++) {
       $p_image[] = $get['p_image'.$i];
   if ($i > 4) {
      break;
   }
?>
   <li data-uk-slideshow-item="<?php echo $i ?>">
       <img src="<?php echo $get['p_image'.$i]; ?>">
   </li>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

why this is not work, thanks for your help before :)

Comment: is `$get` suppose to be `$_GET`?? i really dont understand this.

Comment: not $_GET, just $get for $get = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

Comment: you should be using a multi-d array not an incremented varabel

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Array is the perfect way to handle multiple similar values. You should really not consider making separate variables for this.

Still, in order to create dynamic variables, you need to use an additional `$`, and wrap them in curly braces `{..}`:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $j_image; $i++) {
       // Create string for dynamic variable name and put it inside curly braces
       // use $ in front to define this as a new variable
       ${'p_image'.$i} = $get['p_image'.$i];
   if ($i > 4) {
      break;
   }
```

Comment: so how can i make the variable for echo?
echo $p_image[1] or echo $p_image.$i ???

Comment: no, cause i set the "echo" inside "for" loop not one by one outside "for" loop

Comment: @bayu666 then use `echo ${'p_image'.$i};`

Comment: @bayu666 try this `echo $get['p_image'.$i];` and see if you still get the value ?

Comment: im still not get value :( omg really really make me frustrated right now

Comment: @bayu666 please edit the question and show how you are creating the `$get` array.

Comment: @bayu666 What are the columns in your `tb_produk` table ?

Comment: column: p_image1 | p_image2 | p_image3 | p_image4 | p_image5 .... till p_image9 |

like that

Comment: @bayu666 just do a print_r(`$get`) and see whether your query is actually returning any result or not. Also echo the query string itself, and run in MySQL directly, to check whether query actually returns something or not.

Comment: @bayu666 check the query please. It is definitely not returning any result for the `$id`

Comment: oke, i was fixed it, i just include the query MySQL inside "for" loop, and its work, thanks Mr. Madhur Bhaiya..

Comment: You do know that it is very obvious that you are serial downvoting me. I have seen your voting stats.

Comment: @Andreas and you are doing the same as well. don't start something when you can't bear it.

Comment: @Andreas down vote without explanation on an accepted answer. Secondly, there is one DV on one of my question as well.

Comment: Without explanation? My answer is the explanation! I don't know about your questions. Haven't looked at them.

Answer (score 0):

I think creating dynamic named variables is just a way to make things harder than it is.
Instead I believe fixing the problem is the solution.

Dynamic variables is just harder to work with than arrays and will make bugs in your code some day.

Here I use a foreach on the $get array which means it will loop the items there is and we don't have to count and guess stuff.
Then I removed this new array you created as I don't see the point of it and instead go directly to the output part with my foreach variable $image.
I also keep the code in PHP and echo the html as I find that easier to read, but that is purely opinion and you can do whichever you want.

```
$i=1;
foreach($get as $image){
   if ($i > 4) {
      break;
   }

   echo "<li data-uk-slideshow-item=" . $i .">\n";
   echo '    <img src="' . $image . '">' . "\n";
   echo "</li>\n";
   $i++;

}
```

Example output:

```
<li data-uk-slideshow-item=1>
    <img src="1">
</li>
<li data-uk-slideshow-item=2>
    <img src="2">
</li>
<li data-uk-slideshow-item=3>
    <img src="3">
</li>
<li data-uk-slideshow-item=4>
    <img src="4">
</li>
```

Not sure if your code is supposed to output four or five items.
But I just left the if and break as it was in your code.

https://3v4l.org/MrAng